# "REQUEST NOT AUTHORIZED" Squareup payment integration on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, square

I am planning to use Square Plugin (Caldera Forms) to recieve payment on my WordPress developed website.

I have Input the necessary sandbox ID from my developer dashboard In Square into the area required on WordPress.

However, whenever I include my card payment info on the website and try to pay, it says "REQUEST NOT AUTHORIZED"

I've troubleshoot a lot of articles online regarding it but nothing has worked. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the developer of the Square plugin for help with this?

Comment: Hello and thank you for responding. Yes I have reached out to Square on Support and Twitter. All they did is send me link of Articles that doesn't solve the error.